# Error in the IUPAC Gold Book definitions of exergonic, endergonic, exothermic and endothermic?

Tags: thermodynamics, definitions

All definitions in the IUPAC Gold Book refer to *standard* values:

> **exergonic reaction (exoergic reaction)** [[link](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/E02262)]
>
> This expression is often applied to a reaction for which the overall
> *standard* Gibbs energy change ΔG° is negative. Some workers use this
> term with reference to a negative value of ΔH° at the absolute zero of
> temperature.

> **endergonic reaction (endoergic reaction)** [[link](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/E02091)]
>
> This is usually taken to be a reaction for which the overall *standard*
> Gibbs energy change ΔG° is positive. Some workers use this term with
> respect to a positive value of ΔH° at the absolute zero of
> temperature.

> **exothermic reaction** [[link](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/E02269)]
>
> A reaction for which the overall *standard* enthalpy change ΔH° is
> negative.

> **endothermic reaction** [[link](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/E02095)]
>
> A reaction for which the overall *standard* enthalpy change ΔH° is
> positive.

Shouldn't all these terms characterize values of ΔG and ΔH at any given condition, independently to any standard state?

Is there another recognized official source for the definition of those terms?

**Edit**: In view of the discussion starting to build up in the comments to this question, please note that I am *not* asking about the definition of standard state in thermodynamics.

Comment: The word "standard" means that the measurements have been made when the initial and the final state are at the same temperature and pressure (25°C, 1 atm.)

Comment: My question was maybe not clear. I have rephrased it. I meant "independently to any standard state".

Comment: The entry about exergonic reactions links to the open access publication in [PAC](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1351/pac199668010149/html). I understand the footnote on p. 164 of this paper as "... [standard refers] to the standard concentration [of the reagents] (usually $1 \mathrm{mol\, dm^{-3}}$)" to prevent too large deviation between *concentration* of the reagents, and *their activity*.  Maurice' criteria (25°C and 1 atm) might be included, or set on top.  Content in square brackets is my added reading, which may be wrong.

Comment: Please don't propose `iupac` tag. See https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3801.

Comment: The definition of standard conditions does _not_ include temperature. And standard pressure is 1 bar (not 1 atm).

Comment: @Long Bye, bye, to *T* in [SATP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure) ?

Comment: @buttonwood Despite the names, STP and SATP are not the same as the _standard_ state for thermodynamic quantities. See also [Notation for states and processes, significance of the word standard in chemical thermodynamics, and remarks on commonly tabulated forms of thermodynamic functions (IUPAC Recommendations 1981)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac198254061239): “The above definitions of standard states make no reference to fixed temperature. Hence, it is possible to have an infinite number of standard states of a substance as the temperature varies. (…)”

Comment: @Loong With this specific reference in hand, I recommend you are going to transfer your comment above (including link to the OA publication) into an answer.  As such, it is easier to recognize (both by visually inspection and appreciating your crawl through the literature to identify the relevant reference).

Comment: I agree that IUPAC's decision to tie the definitions of exothermic and endothermic to stanadard pressure is problematic, since it disconnects them from the direction of heat flow.  I discuss this here:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/122102/why-are-iupacs-definitions-of-exo-and-endothermic-disconnected-from-the-direct

Comment: @theorist Indeed, your post raises exactly the underlying questions I had. So it seems that this question doesn't have a clear answer yet. I have contacted someone from the IUPAC pointing to your question. Let see where it leads...